# replace collection in a view

Tags: backbone.js

I want to replace a collection inside a view. I use the reset command like this:

```
var maColl=mContent.get(ici).get("svgParameterList");  
msvgParameterListView.collection.reset(maColl);
```

A `JSON.stringify` gives this :

**maColl**

```
    [{"id":"x","name":"x"},....{"id":"style","name":"style"}]
```

**msvgParameterListView.collection**

```
    [[{"id":"x","name":"x"},....{"id":"style","name":"style"}]]
```

Now, i have my collection in an array, so when i render it return null value.

How to change array of collection into collection ?
In short, how to make msvgParameterListView.collection equal to maColl ?

Note the `[[  ]]` for the new collection.
Note maColl is a collection inside another collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to reset a collection with the models of another collection? [`collection.toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) is your friend:

> **toJSON** *collection.toJSON()*
>   Return an array containing the attributes hash of each model in the collection. This can be used to
>   serialize and persist the collection as a whole. The name of this
>   method is a bit confusing, because it conforms to JavaScript's JSON
>   API.

which could be applied like this

```
msvgParameterListView.collection.reset(maColl.toJSON());
```

Or if you want to keep a reference to the original models, pass `maColl.models`

```
msvgParameterListView.collection.reset(maColl.models);
```

Passing directly a collection to `reset` will only confuse Backbone.

Comment: Thanks ! maColl.models work perfectly because it keeps value.